# Bootstrap 4.1 flex 50%-high scroll list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Trying to create a full-screen layout with a top and bottom half. Top half should contain a list of items that should have a scroll-bar if it exceeds half of the screen height.

After some searching, I was able to get a workable solution using following markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <main role="main" class="container-fluid d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-fill bg-primary" style="min-height:100vh;">
      <div class="col-sm h-100">
        <div class="row h-50 bg-warning" style="overflow:scroll;">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div>
              <ul class="">
                <li class="">Series 100</li>
                <li class="">Series 200</li>
                <li class="">Series 300</li>
                <li class="">Series 400</li>
                <li class="">Series 500</li>
                <li class="">Series 600</li>
                <li class="">Series 700</li>
                <li class="">Series 800</li>
                <li class="">Series 900</li>
                <li class="">Series 1000</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50 bg-success">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div>
              test
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </main>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0zbcr7mg/4/ (make sure output window is reduced to the point where whole list doesn't fit in)

However, once I added more items to the list, the layout broke down - list still had a scrollbar, but it was taking more than 50% of the output window's heigh:

http://jsfiddle.net/0zbcr7mg/3/

What changes should I make in the mark-up to behave consistently regardless of the amount of elements in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the row `min-height:100vh` to `height:100vh`...

http://jsfiddle.net/tokep2gn/

```
<div id="app">
    <main role="main" class="container-fluid d-flex">
        <div class="row flex-fill bg-primary" style="height: 100vh;">
            <div class="col-sm h-100">
                <div class="row h-50 bg-warning" style="overflow:scroll;">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="">
                                <li class="">Series 100</li>
                                <li class="">Series 200</li>
                                <li class="">Series 300</li>
                                <li class="">Series 400</li>
                                <li class="">Series 500</li>
                                <li class="">Series 600</li>
                                <li class="">Series 700</li>
                                <li class="">Series 800</li>
                                <li class="">Series 900</li>
                                <li class="">Series 1000</li>
                <li class="">Series 100</li>
                                <li class="">Series 200</li>
                                <li class="">Series 300</li>
                                <li class="">Series 400</li>
                                <li class="">Series 500</li>
                                <li class="">Series 600</li>
                                <li class="">Series 700</li>
                                <li class="">Series 800</li>
                                <li class="">Series 900</li>
                                <li class="">Series 1000</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row h-50 bg-success">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <div>
                            test
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your code a bit by utilizing 2x sections with a viewport height of 50% like this

HTML

```
<section id="top">
  <ul>
    <li class="">Series 100</li>
    <li class="">Series 200</li>
    <li class="">Series 300</li>
    <li class="">Series 400</li>
    <li class="">Series 500</li>
    <li class="">Series 600</li>
    <li class="">Series 700</li>
    <li class="">Series 800</li>
    <li class="">Series 900</li>
    <li class="">Series 1000</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="bottom">
  <ul>
    <li class="">Series 100</li>
    <li class="">Series 200</li>
    <li class="">Series 300</li>
    <li class="">Series 400</li>
    <li class="">Series 500</li>
    <li class="">Series 600</li>
    <li class="">Series 700</li>
    <li class="">Series 800</li>
    <li class="">Series 900</li>
    <li class="">Series 1000</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  overflow: auto; /* Allows for scroll without scrollbars created by overflow: scroll;  */
}

#bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can check next approach for what you are looking:

**1)** The `root` div should always have assigned a `100vh` value.

**2)** The main layout is one `row` using a setup of two `col-12` and each one of they having exactly `50%` of the `height`.

I also filled the `ul` list from **Javascript** for keep the markup cleaner.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

    for (var i = 100; i <= 2000; i += 100)
    {
        $(".custom-list").append("<li>Series " + i + "</li>");
    }
    
});
```

```css
#app {
    height: 100vh;
}

#bottom-section, #top-section {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="app">
<main role="main" class="container-fluid h-100">
<div class="row bg-primary h-100">

  <div id="top-section" class="col-12 h-50 bg-warning">
    <ul class="custom-list"></ul>
  </div>

  <div id="bottom-section" class="col-12 h-50 bg-success">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
```